# How can I get the same margin to a verbatim environment as the fleqn option gives to equation

Tags: margins, verbatim

When I use a `verbatim` environment, I'd like to have some margin, of the same length as those provided by the `fleqn` option when using an `equation` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation*}
  e^{iπ}=-1
\end{equation*}

\begin{verbatim}
\\ Can I have margin ?
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fleqn` option causes displayed math expressions to be placed at a fixed indent from the left margin; this fixed indent is controlled by `\mathindent`, so you need a verbatim environment with this same indentation from the left margin. Below I show two options.

Using the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package all you have to do is to set

```
\fvset{xleftmargin=\mathindent}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\fvset{xleftmargin=\mathindent}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation*}
  e^{iπ}=-1
\end{equation*}
\begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim line.
\\ Now there's indentation
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also easily achieve this with more powerful packages, such as [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings), with the additional advantage of great customization possibilities, automatic line breaks, captions, titles, and many more:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  xleftmargin=\mathindent,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation*}
  e^{iπ}=-1
\end{equation*}
\begin{lstlisting}
Verbatim line.
\\ Now there's indentation
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mindent}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin0pt \leftmargin\mathindent}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}

\begin{document} 

Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation*}
  e^{iπ}=-1
\end{equation*}

\begin{mindent}
\begin{verbatim}
\\ Can I have margin ?
\end{verbatim}
\end{mindent}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,verbatim,showframe}

\newenvironment{myverbatim}%
{\par\hspace*{\dimexpr-\parindent+\mathindent\relax}%
\minipage{\dimexpr\linewidth-\mathindent\relax}\verbatim}%
{\endverbatim\endminipage}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum
\begin{equation*}
  e^{iπ}=-1
\end{equation*}
\begin{myverbatim}
\\ Can I have margin ?
\\ Can I have margin ?
\end{myverbatim}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `minipage` needs to be of width equal to `\dimexpr\linewidth-\mathindent\relax`; otherwise, overfull `\hbox`es will appear.